# React Native StackOverflowError Build Failure

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I'm excited to be a part of this community. I'm currently working on a React Native app using Expo and Glassfy, and I've run into a challenging issue that's been perplexing me for several days now.

The Problem:
When I attempt to run the app using the command npx react-native run-android, I encounter the following error:

```
2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 56s
104 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 100 up-to-date
error Failed to build the app.
```

Request for Help:
I'm reaching out to this community in the hopes of finding some guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Unfortunately, the error message, "StackOverflowError," doesn't provide me with enough information to pinpoint the root cause.

What I've Tried So Far:

I've attempted running with various debugging options, but the error message remains cryptic.
I've checked my codebase for potential recursive loops or infinite calls, but haven't been successful in identifying any obvious issues.
How You Can Help:
If anyone has encountered a similar problem or has insights into how to approach debugging a StackOverflowError in a React Native project, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Even a general guideline on where to start looking for the problem would be incredibly valuable.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide. I'm eager to learn from this experience and get back on track with my project.

Best regards,

Comment: Try with another react native sample to validate if it is something on your workspace config (linux, android, java, graddle, etc) or in your source code.

Comment: Other react-native projects compiles to android fine

Answer (score -1):

This error typically occurs when a function or method calls itself recursively without a proper exit condition, causing the stack to overflow.

Look for any recursive function calls in your code and ensure that they have a proper exit condition.

Comment: Tom is not running own code but a build system.

Comment: Tried deleting almost everything from the code base to pinpoint where that could be and it still does it, and now its just a blank page with a view